Complex roots of real polynomials and real roots of their derivatives
I have a question that popped up while working on an optimization problem. Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of order $2n$ with real coefficients that doesn't have any real roots. I'm interested in the real roots of $f'(x)$. I'm motivated by the case $n=1$, where the real part of the complex roots of $f(x)$ equals the real root of $f'(x)$. Is this the case for other $n$? Can we make a general statement?

Are you familiar with the Gauss-Lucas theorem, which states that the zeros of $p'$ lie in the convex hull of the roots of $p$? In the case of $p$ quadratic, that means that $p'$ must have a root on the line segment joining the two roots of $p$.  Since $p'$ has a real root, your observation follows. But that is really very special to quadratics. Still, you could view Gauss-Lucas as a generalization of this fact.

I was aware of Gauss-Lucas, but I didn't realize its implications for the quadratic polynomial. I think that's a convincing argument that there is no reason to believe that it holds for other $n$. Thank you!

As Jair Taylor points out in a comment, your best bet for the general case is the Gauss-Lucas Theorem. Applied to quartic equations with two sets of complex conjugate roots, the theorem implies that in general the roots of the quartic are at the vertices of a quadrilateral in the complex plane and the roots of the derivative (real and otherwise) lie inside this quadrilateral.
In some cases the quadrilateral can be collapsed to a straight line parallel to the imaginary axis, in which case the roots all have the same real part and that real number is the only real zero of the derivative. The simplest example is the quartic $ax^4+bx^2+c$ with all coefficients positive and $b^2\ge4ac$.

Thanks a lot for your helpful answer! Are you aware of any general conditions for the roots to all have the same real part?

Let $2n$ be the degree and $a_{2n}x^{2n}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}$ be the two leading terms. Define $y=x-h, h=a_{2n-1}/(2na_{2n})$ If the equation for $y$ contains only even powers and $y^2$ has all its roots real and nonpositive, the original polynomial has all roots with real part $h$.
